# Multiple activation functions with TensorFlow estimator DNNClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow

I just want to know if is it possible to use [tf.estimator.DNNClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier) with multiple different activation functions. I mean, could I use a DNNClassifier estimator which use different activation functions for different layers?

For example, if I have a three layers model, could I use for the first layer a *sigmoid* function, for the second one a *ReLu* function and finally for the last one a *tanh* function?

I would like to know if it isn't possible to do it with [DNNClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier) how can I do it by a easy way.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a very old question, but for anyone coming from Google:

According to the documentation provided by Tensor Flow, `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier` has the parameter `activation_fn` which is described by:

`Activation function applied to each layer. If None, will use tf.nn.relu`

Therefore, this model only takes one activation function and uses it on all layers. That being said, Tensor Flow notes:

`Warning: Estimators are not recommended for new code. Estimators run v1.Session-style code which is more difficult to write correctly, and can behave unexpectedly, especially when combined with TF 2 code. Estimators do fall under our compatibility guarantees, but will receive no fixes other than security vulnerabilities. See the migration guide for details.`

Therefore, to solve this problem and be compatible with Tensor Flow's recommendations one can use keras to create the desired DNN layer by layer. As shown in the example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#:%7E:text=inputs%20and%20outputs-,%3A,-import%20tensorflow%20as):

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

The activation function for each layer can be specified when creating each layer. For more on keras.layers see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers#classes).